# flask /python local storage issue

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, local-storage

I am working on a website where I want to save files locally on the computer.

I will be creating user profiles and each user can save files.

I just want this one user that's why I want to do this on my system locally only.

How can I save the files and retrieve them from a location on my system only?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can  you be more specific about what you are trying to do and what you have tried? Are you trying to store files on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the Flaskr tutorial? I recently started using Flask, and it helped me.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/introduction/

You can also follow along at the tutorial GitHub page, which includes all of the code:

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr/

The tutorial covers setting up sessions for an individual user, which I think will solve part of your problem.

(I know this doesn't fully answer your question, but I do not have enough reputation to comment, otherwise I would have included the links there.)